# regex to get all between @ and @ in multilines text

Tags: java, android, regex

i hope you're fine.

example i have a text with tags
@tag
i want to get all text between the tags as parts (not as one, look at the picture at the end, at the top, the result is 4 matches and not one). the problem is inside the text of every tag maybe contains the symbol @, and this will cut my result matches.

i tried several times with different regex but alwas without success

the final regex i use is :

```
((^(@))|[^\"]@)[^(@)]+\}\n
```

the example centent text (that i use for trying) :

```
@main.xml
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}


@main.xml_fab
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"@firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}


@main.xml
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}

j
@main.xml_fab
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"center"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
{"adSize":"","adUnitId":"","alpha":1.0,"checked":0,"choiceMode":0,"clickable":1,"convert":"","customView":"","dividerHeight":1,"enabled":1,"firstDayOfWeek":1,"id":"_fab","image":{"rotate":0,"scaleType":"CENTER"},"indeterminate":"false","index":0,"inject":"","layout":{"backgroundColor":16777215,"borderColor":-16740915,"gravity"}
```

and this is picture show my problem

[image]

i want to get the whole parts between @tag1 and @tag2,3,4...ect,
how can i deal with the symbol @ if it is inside the content of tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure of the use of `[^\"]@` in your expression... What is its purpose? could you provide an example?

Anyway you have to remove @ from the list of excluded characters. and change the way you look a the end of your section. Try:

```
^@[^(]+?\}\n(?=\@|$)
```

- `^@` matches @ at the beginning of a line
- `[^(]+?` matches any character expect `(` one or more times until (`?` makes it lazy) the next occurrence of the next element...
- `\}\n` your segments always end with a curly bracket followed by a new line
- `(?=\@|$)` the critical part: a lookahead that ensures the following element is either a `@` (new segment) or the end of the file, without capturing it. That way you don't cut a segment before its end and you can still capture the beginning of the next segment.

Try a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbIVdt/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```java
(?m)^@.+(?:\n.+)*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/EoElMN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the line due to (?m)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```